# connecting emulator to internet

Tags: android, emulation

I have recently started learning the Google Maps API from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/) and I did exactly what  it was there. I got a key and I used it. But at last the problem was that the map was not displaying!!

I tried all the possible ways to connect the emulator to the internet. My Internet connection has
a proxy server and I tried to specify that from the `command line`, from the eclipse itself by going into the run->configurations ... ans so on.

I even changed the proxy settings of the emulator from the `settings` option in the emulator. The good news is that the `browser` was working nicely, but not my app :(. Even I tried to launch the inbuilt `google maps` app in the emulator.

It was showing a message as follows:

```
There is no working data connection. App exiting.
```

I don't know why this is happening?. One more thing is that i didn't changed the `DNS` settings for the emulator. Will that be a problem? I don't think so because if it were, then browser wouldn't had ran in the first place. I am using `Eclipse Indigo`.

Plz help with this weird problem.. Thanx...

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the browser works OK, it means that your internet connection is fine. I don't think you need to make specifig config for the network.

My guess is that there is an issue with your api key. You need to create the MD5 signature of your debug certificate, then get the api key associated with it, and use this key in the layout where the mapview is inserted. In the following command line, all that you are supposed to edit is the location of your keystore file :

keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\users\ravi.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

Be careful, if you type a wrong password, you will still get MD5 signature, but it will be wrong, and as a result the map would not display.

Comment: When you follow the steps in the link you gave in your question, step 3 tells you how to create the MD5 signature of your debug certificate. Then you must use this signature to generate you api key, which you will use in your xml layout. Are you clear with those steps ?
I think you made something wrong about step 3, ie the generation of the MD5 signature. Be sure to specify "android" as the "storepass" and "keypass" parameters, ie make sure your command line ends with "-storepass android -keypass android"

Comment: I got a key saying that `This key is good for all apps signed with your certificate...`, i just pasted that in the `main.xml` and tried to run the program. The logcat was showing...  `Couldn't get connection factory client`.. Still i don't get whats happening...

Comment: I met the exact same message before, and everytime it was because my apikey was invalid, or because i signed the application with a certificate that was not associated with the correct key.

How do you run you app ? Directly from Eclipse ? If so, do you "run" it or "debug" it ? (the two buttons are next to each other).

Comment: titol i "run" it...does this make any difference?? and one more thing is that i have about 6 JDKs , so which one to choose to get the api key??

Comment: 1. Im not sure if run or debug makes a difference, but try to debug it
2. I am not clear with your question, and I'm not sure you're clear either. Do you have 6 JDKS On your computer (it would be quite surprising) ? Or do you mean you have 6 virtual devices ?

Comment: OK... Anyway, if keytool returns an answer, and if your application runs, JDKS should not be the problem.

Comment: at last i got it!!! I generated another key with different JDK and that worked!!! thanx alot...

Comment: Great, can you tell me which JDK you were using previously and which you are using now ? 
Thanks for the info,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try to run the emulator from the console. 
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

Be sure to pass the following commands: (8.8.8.8 is a DNS from Google)

```
-http-proxy <proxy>
-dns-server 8.8.8.8
-verbose
```

If there is any output it might point out the problem further. Possibly the browser has a build in fallback DNS server?

Comment: Actually when i checked the `logcat` i saw something called `checkin failed UnknownHostExecption https://android.clients.google.com`. Is this the actual problem??

Comment: and when I try to execute with the above specified command i was getting a very big output!!! in the command line...

Comment: what r u using, either eclipse or netbeans. If u r using eclipse, then try it. 1. click on to DDMS 2. Emulator control 3. There is telephone status, set value "Home" for data. Try it...